# Map to view on custom field name - one-to-one relationship

Tags: view, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-2000

I am unable to get NHibernate to map the `AccountCode` column of the `Beneficiary` table `AccountCode` column in this one-to-one relationship (each `Account` has a single `Beneficiary`, each `Beneficiary` has a single `Account`).

Classes:

```
public class Account
{
    ...
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; protected set; }
}

public class Beneficiary
{
    ...
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; protected set; }
    public virtual BeneficiaryGroup Group { get; protected set; }
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Account AS
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(ACCNT_NAME)) AS Name, 
                    RTRIM(LTRIM(ACCNT_CODE)) AS Code
    FROM myremoteserver.schema.tablename
    WHERE ACCNT_TYPE NOT IN ('B', 'P')


CREATE TABLE dbo.Beneficiary
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    BeneficiaryGroupId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Beneficiaries_BeneficiaryGroup FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.BeneficiaryGroup (Id), 
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    AccountCode VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Beneficiary PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

When trying to use `HasMany` and different variants, NHibernate tries to join on the `Beneficiary.Id` column.

I had tried different variations of `Map`, `References`, `Join` (which tells me that the join already exists) and `HasMany` (which fails, as the relationship is indeed one-to-one).

How can I get NHibernate to map these two classes correctly to their columns?

---

When trying the different fluent mappings, in my `IAutoMappingOverride<Beneficiary>`, the following happens:

```
mapping.HasOne(b => b.Account);
mapping.HasOne(b => b.Account).PropertyRef(sa => sa.Code);
mapping.HasOne(b => b.Account).PropertyRef(sa => sa.Code).ForeignKey("none");
```

The generated SQL uses the `Beneficiary.Id` field instead of the `Beneficiary.AccountCode`. (before you ask, I am using "none" since `Account` is a view, it can't have a key).

```
mapping.Join("AccountCode", x => x.References(y => y.Account));
mapping.Join("Account", b => b.KeyColumn("AccountCode"));
```

Result in `Tried to add join to table 'Account' when already added.`.

And:

```
mapping.Map(b => b.Account, "AccountCode");
mapping.Map(b => b.Account).ReadOnly().Column("AccountCode");
```

Result in:

> Could not determine type for: .Account, , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: 
>   NHibernate.Mapping.Column(AccountCode)

```
mapping.References(b => b.Account).Column("Code");
```

Results in `Invalid column name 'Code'.`.

And:

```
mapping.References(b => b.Account).Column("AccountCode");
mapping.References(b => b.Account).Column("AccountCode").Access.Property();
```

Overrides all my `IReferenceConvention` overrides (mapping some classes to have a `<class name>Code` key column).

When trying `HasMany`:

```
mapping.HasMany<Account>(b => b.Account).KeyColumn("AccountCode");
```

> Custom type does not implement UserCollectionType: .Account

Comment: Versions, if important: NHibernate 3.3.1.4000, FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// in BeneficiaryMapping
mapping.References(b => b.Account)
    .Column("AccountCode" /* of Beneficiary table*/)
    .PropertyRef(a => a.Code); // use the Column of Code as the joincolumn in Account table
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach is similar to Firo's but in a simpler mapping. It uses `References` like he suggest because that's how NH allows you select a property other than the entity primary key property to reference another type. The `PropertyRef` is not necessary since NH "knows" its going to use the `AccountCode` value as the the "key" into the `Account` view.

Here is how to map `Account`:

```
public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        // Code as a psuedo primary key in the view:
        Id(acc => acc.Code)
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(acc => acc.Name);

        // Add other mappings here...

        // Ensure NH doesn't try to update the lookup view:
        ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Here is how `Beneficiary` looks mapped:

```
public class BeneficiaryMap : ClassMap<Beneficiary>
{
    public BeneficiaryMap()
    {
        Id(b => b.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity()
            .UnsavedValue(0);

        Map(b => b.Name);
        // Other mapped properties...

        References<BeneficiaryGroup>(b => b.Group, "BeneficiaryGroupId");
        References<Account>(b => b.Account, "AccountCode");
    }
}
```